# Elasticsearch shows data as buffer type in Kibana

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, indexing, data-visualization, kibana

I am trying to index one json to elastic search.

It seems to be working fine as it is not giving any error.

I have indexed document as below.

```js
await client.index({
            id: fieldId.toString(),
            index: 'project_documents_textfielddata',
            body: {
              FieldId: fieldId,
              DocumentId: documentId,
              Value: fieldData.fieldHTMLText,
            },
            routing: projectId.toString(),
          });
```

But in elasticsearch kibana it is showing as buffer type as below (I have truncated buffer as it was very long).

```json
{
  "_index": "documenttextfile.files",
  "_id": "6252ab411deaba21fd877c26",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": 1,
  "_routing": "62505a765ff176cd491f1d1e",
  "_source": {
    "id": "6252ab411deaba21fd877c26",
    "Content": {
      "type": "Buffer",
      "data": [
        10,
     // Some extra large binary content removed for convenient
      48,
      56,
      50,
    ],
    "id": [
      "6252ab411deaba21fd877c26"
    ],
    "Content.type.keyword": [
      "Buffer"
    ]
  }
}
```

So how can I see my data as is (i.e. in json format) in Kibana. I've seen many tutorials on Kibana, they are able to see data in plain text instead of buffer.

Or am I doing anything wrong while indexing? I am basically trying to see the data the way we can see in mongodb compass.

Comment: You're showing data from two unrelated indexes, i.e.`project_documents_textfielddata` and `documenttextfile.files`. Aside from that, your `fieldData.fieldHTMLText` is probably of type `Buffer` and you simply need to call `toString()` on it, as in `fieldData.fieldHTMLText.toString()` in order to transform the buffer to a string.

Comment: Oh. Got it. This kibanna was very new to me so I only checked this "text" keyword. As I was following some tutorials. Now I could see that. Should I delete the question?

Comment: Or should I keep it open for negative voting and you can add answer?

Comment: Sorry for the question but I am like very very new to this Kibanna so things were bit confusing for me. And thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fieldData.fieldHTMLText`field is probably of type `Buffer` and you simply need to call `fieldData.fieldHTMLText.toString()`on it in order to transform the buffer to a string.

PS: the problem has nothing to do with Kibana which shows you exactly what you're sending to Elasticsearch, i.e. a Buffer. So the problem is more related to your understand of Node.js data structures (i.e. Buffer vs string) ;-)

Comment: Yes. I was looking at different index as I was very new to both elastic search and kibana and this "text" keyword were in both of the index (I didn't know that I had also indexed that buffer index at other place) which kept me baffled. Thanks a lot for this quick solution.